# Question on Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

$S$ is a non-empty subset of a Hilbert Space $H$, show that the set of all linear combinations of vectors in $S$ is dense in $H\Leftrightarrow S^{\bot}=\{0\}$

I have been able to show  $\Rightarrow$  direction : Call the set of all linear combinations of vectors in $S$ as $S_1$ Say, $v\in S^{\bot}, \exists$ a sequence $v_n$ in $S_1$ such that $v_n\rightarrow v$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $v_n\bot v $ 
 $\forall n\in\mathbf{N}$ $\therefore \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|v_n-v\|^2=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|v_n\|^2+\|v\|^2=2\|v\|^2=0 \Rightarrow v=0$

I am struggling with the other implication, We have $S^{\bot\bot}=H$, need to show closure of $S_1$ is $S^{\bot\bot}=H$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $\left(\overline{\operatorname{span}S}\right)^\perp = S^\perp$. The Riesz projection theorem implies $$\left(\overline{\operatorname{span}S}\right)\oplus \left(\overline{\operatorname{span}S}\right)^\perp = H$$
so $$\text{linear span of } S \text{ is dense in } H \iff\overline{\operatorname{span}S} = H \iff \left(\overline{\operatorname{span}S}\right)^\perp = \{0\} \iff S^\perp = \{0\}$$

Answer (score 1):

The adherence $\bar S_1$ of $S_1$ is a vector subspace, if $S_1$ is not dense, there exists $x$ which is not in $\bar{S_1}$. The linear form defined on $\bar{S_1}\oplus\mathbb{C}x$ by $f(\bar{S_1})=0, f(x)=1$ can be extended to $H$ by $g$ since it is continuous (Hahn Banach). Use te Riesz representation theorem to write $g=\langle x_0,.\rangle$. This implies that $x_0$ is in the orthogonal of $\bar{S_1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I am not supposed to use Hahn banach for this question, I got an idea from your solution, please hear me out. If $\bar{S_1} \neq H$, then $\exists$ non-zero $v\in \bar {S_1} ^{\bot}  $, but $S_1 \subseteq \bar {S_1}\Rightarrow S_1^{\bot}\supseteq \bar{S_1}^{\bot} $ Now I want to say that $S^{\bot}=0\Rightarrow S_1 ^{\bot}=0$, so  $\bar{S_1}^{\bot} =0$ , is this correct : $S^{\bot}=0\Rightarrow S_1 ^{\bot}=0$

Comment: how you know the existence of $v$ ?

Comment: A theorem says that : If $M$ is a proper closed linear subspace of a Hilbert space $H$, then $\exists$ a non zero vector $z_0$ in $H$ such that $z_0\bot M$

Comment: that's true I use Hahn Banach and Riez to show that theorem, you can show it also by considering a point which realize $d(x,\bar{S_1})$.